# How to remove index.php from URLs with enabled URL Rewriting on localhost

Tags: url, sef, localhost

I have got a problem in Joomla..
I think, it is just a link problem maybe from the server-side. I don't know!

```
I renamed htacess.txt to .htaccess from my root folder before activated URL Rewriting.
```

WebSite's page gets response that 404 not found !!

```
Example: /localhost/about.html
```

[image]

### ```
But I get a response when I put to "index.php" in the URL
```

/localhost/index.php/about.html

[image]
then everything is seen.

## I want to web site run localhost/about.html

Would I change something from .htaccess.txt or db ?

Please help me ? And I am sorry my bad english :((

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if apache rewrite_module ia active in your localhost

Comment: That sounds good! I checked that and I can't active from wamp server. I looked at httpd.conf and I removed to this sign "# "(Load rewrite_module) but The problem unchanged. So I look at the wamp apache server,maybe there is another problem. Thanks dude ! @Piero Marsilio

Comment: Don not forget to Restart Apache services after changes in httpd.conf, of course...

Comment: Always @Mikan but , I find the solutions. And it is so complicated and funny. Beacuse  I suppose that, the htaccess.txt to .htacess  but I don't. Someone else may encounter this problem so There is a link  [link] (https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=605442) .  The file name changes from cmd :)) Thanks again ! cheers